# Limit number of facebook request allowed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

My previous facebook developer account was blocked due I guess of making to many requests (No reason given by them and no answer after trying to contact them).

So before fall in the same issue with a new account. I would like to know if some has some relevant info or experience of how much request per second or hour can be made safetly to Facebook's API before been mark as abuse of service and been banned.

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure your guess is wrong. Too many requests would make you run into the Rate Limits, and that would cause the API to answer with an error/exception - but that has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with your developer account.

Comment: Then is a mystery for me cause I don't know why was the ban about. The only thing i was using it was for importing events from facebook pages through a wordpress plugin and logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article about rate limits in the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting